# How to get the value of all inputs in a form

Tags: jquery, forms, input

**Code:**

```
<form name="newform" action="test.php" method="post"  class="form-horizontal input-prepend" id="newform">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="test1">test1</label>
    <input type="text" name="test1" class="form-control" id="test1" placeholder="">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="test2">test2</label>
    <input type="text" name="test2" class="form-control" id="test2" placeholder="">
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="test3">test3</label>
    <input type="text" name="test3" class="form-control" id="test3" placeholder="">
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="test1">test4</label>
    <input type="text" name="test4" class="form-control" id="test4" placeholder="">
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="test5">test5</label>
    <input type="text" name="test5" class="form-control" id="test5" placeholder="">
  </div>

</form>
```

In order to get an input's value, we can use its `id`, for example `alert($("#test5").val())`, but how to get the input value sequentially from the beginning of the form when we do not know the `id` of the input?

For my test code I can get value using code:

```
var value1 = $("test1").val();
var value2 = $("test2").val();
var value3 = $("test3").val();
var value4 = $("test4").val();
var value5 = $("test5").val();
```

Does anyone have any ideas about how to get values when we don't know an input's `id`?

Comment: What do you want, an array?

Comment: You want to know the input ids, why would you want to parse it otherwise? Sure you can't say it about objects in general, but you are pretty specific when it comes to forms.

Comment: @DavidThomas if it really i want get each value separately. But array will be good too.

Comment: @Jonast92 in my test code all inputs have id, but how get theys values when we dont know id inputs ?

Comment: Explain what end-result you want, and then we'll work out how to help you get it. Otherwise we're just guessing, based on what we know will, or *can*, work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
$('form').serialize();
```

or:

```
var values = [];
$('input').each(function() {
    values.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: The second snippet will return values for unchecked checkboxes, which may be undesirable.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are using jQuery.

```
 $('form[name="newForm"]').serializeArray();
```

this yields  an array that looks like:

```
[{name:'test1', value:'value1'},...]
```

See [jQuery serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of options.

**By Tag**

Use `$('input')` to get all inputs on the entire page. This is not constrained to any specific form.

**Combined Selectors**

You can combine selectors, `$('input,select')`

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/s5jgd/

**By Tag, within element**

You can use `find` to retrieve all inputs from a specific element. For example:

`$('#myForm').find('input');`

You can also use this approach with combined selectors:

`$('#myForm').find('input,select');`

**Using the `form.elements` collection**

There is a collection of elements, accessed with `$('#myForm').elements`

**By giving all elements a class**

This is the most flexible option, use `$('.myElementClass')`

**Serialize**

jQuery provides a method for serializing a form's data; it will give you a list of all the elements in a string format that you can use for requests.

`$('#myForm').serialize()` outputs (for example) this url encoded string: `myElementA=my+input&myElementB=my+input+c&myElementC=my+input+c`

`$('#myForm').serializeArray()` is similar, but instead of a string, you get an object, with the form element names as keys corresponding to the current values. It would look like this:

`{"myElementA":"my input", "myElementB":"my input b", "myElementC":"my input c"}`

**Conclusion**

All told, this is basic jQuery usage. I recommend sitting down with the manual and some tutorials to expand your jQuery-foo.

**Documentation**

- jQuery Basics - http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/jquery-basics
- `jQuery.find` - http://api.jquery.com/find/
- `jQuery.serialize` - http://api.jquery.com/serialize/
- Using AJAX and jQuery to submit a form (see examples) - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 3):

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Yw4Hc/3/

```
$('input.form-control').each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('name') + " = " + $(this).val()); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jQuery `each()` function

```
$(".form-control").each(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the `form` an id (eg. `test-form`) and then you can do:

```
var formValues = $('#test-form').serialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array of values, you can project them from the `<input>` elements through [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) chained into [get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
var values = $("input[type=text]").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Several ways, I imagine, depending on what you're going to do with it.

For example, you can select all of the inputs in the form:

```
$('form input')
```

This would return an array of jQuery objects representing all of the inputs.  Then you can loop through that array and get the `.val()` of each one.

Another option might be to serialize the whole form into a JSON object:

```
var data = $('form').serialize();
```

Then you can manipulate that JSON object (`data`) however you want or pull values from it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var inputValues = $("#newform .form-group input:text").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Something similiar to this should work.

> var value5 = $("#newform").find("input").get(5).val();